# do asynchronous calls in order and repeating on error

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, async-await, discord.io

i'm curently trying to implement a discord bot using https://github.com/izy521/discord.io that reacts to all messages with letters in a specific order. if one of those calls should fail, it is supposed to repeat it again until it succeeds before moving on to the next letter.

in my example im trying to react with the letters "A" and "G" in that particular order, but when spamming messages the reactions will somtimes not be in order.

```
async function reactUntilSuccess(mID, channelID, letter){
        await bot.addReaction({channelID,messageID: mID,reaction: letter},
            async function(err,res){
                        
                if (err==null){
                    //reaction sucessul, continue to next letter
                    return;         
                }
                else {
                    //wait a bit and try again
                    await sleep(200)
                    await reactUntilSuccess(mID, channelID, letter)
                }   
            })
            
            
        
}   

//reacts with A and G to message
async function reactString(mID, channelID){
    await asyncForEach(["",""], async (letter) => {
    
        //is supposed to wait until last letter is finished before reacting with next letter
        await reactUntilSuccess(mID, channelID, letter)
        
        await sleep(1000)
    })
}

async function asyncForEach(array, callback) {
  for (let index = 0; index < array.length; index++) {
    await callback(array[index], index, array);
  }
}


bot.on('message', function (user, userID, channelID, message, evt) {
    mID = evt.d.id;
    reactString(mID, channelID, message);
    
})
```

how do i make it so that my reactString function actually waits until the previous reactions are done?

Comment: For starters, you can't just sprinkle `await` wherever you want and expect it to do something useful.  Please go read about what `await` actually does before you try to use it.  Hint: it only does something useful when you're awaiting a promise that is directly connected to the completion of your asynchronous operation.  So, BEFORE you can use it effectively, you need an asynchronous operation that returns a promise.

Comment: an actual explanation where the issue lies and how to fix would be way more useful instead of this elitist "hint". why even bother answering at all if you just expect me to figure it out on my own?

Comment: Look, I just stopped by to try to help.  You need to do a bunch of learning that is beyond what a single answer here can provide.  I was trying to point you in the right direction for that learning.  I figured it was more valuable for you to learn the concepts involved in this type of coding rather than just dump a coding solution in your lap.  And, I was on my mobile where I couldn't really write code for you anyway.  Just trying to help.  Attacking someone who dropped by to help because you were offended by the tone won't help you get more help here.

Comment: look, after hours of trying i just hit a brick wall and asked a specific question on how to solve this problem. but instead of actually answering my question, you decide that thats not the proper way of learning things expect me to figure it out myself. you can't see how that can be frustrating?
especially when looking at working code examples is one of the best ways to understand how stuff works, atleast for me.

Comment: It remains a fact that you need to learn the basics of promises and `await` and how they work together and how to use them as they are being misused in these code examples.  It makes no sense for me to try to redo a general tutorial here in an answer when there are hundreds of tutorials on the web.  I do not understand your code or what you're trying to accomplish with it well enough to even suggest a finished code answer if I wanted to.  Hopefully someone else will come along that is a better match for what you want.